# Нужна ли реализация интерфейса Money?

Tags: java

Есть следующие интерфейсы, необходимо написать метод  Money calculateTotalPrice(Collection shipments), возвращающий сумму стоимости всех товаров (price*amount) с использованием Stream API. Я с Stream API на вы. Нужно ли писать реализацию интерфейса Money? Необходимо ли как-то использовать объект ZERO?

```
public interface Shipment {
    List<Product> getProducts();
}

public interface Product {
    Money getPrice();
    BigDecimal getAmount();
}

public interface Money {
    Money ZERO = new ZeroMoneyImpl();
    Money add(Money other);
    Money multiply(BigDecimal multiplier);
}
```

Comment: метод возвращает Money - думаю результат можно назвать на свое усмотрение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант:

```
Money calculateTotalPrice(Collection<Shipment> shipments){
    return shipments.stream()
            .map(Shipment::getProducts)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(product -> product.getPrice().multiply(product.getAmount()))
            .reduce(Money::add)
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new); // можно так или просто вызвать get() или orElse(null) тут от архитектуры зависит
}
```

По поводу реализации интерфейса, он конечно вам понадобится, но не для этой цели. Тут вам без разницы какая реализация будет, у вас есть контракт в виде интерфейса. О реализации будет заботиться тот, кот будет вызывать ваш метод.

Comment: первые шаги делал как у вас, но почему-то идея на map(Shipment::getProducts) ругалась - говорила, что нестатический метод не может быть использован в статическом контексте. Не подскажите, с чем это связано?

Comment: не видя кода, сложно сказать в чем поблема

Comment: Ну вот такой код и map(Shipment::getProducts) идея подчеркивает красным и говорит, что нестатический метод нельзя вызывать из статического контекста.                                                               public class MainClass {
    public Money calculateTotalPrice(Collection<Product> shipments) {
        return shipments.stream()
                .map(Shipment::getProducts).
    }
}

Comment: У вас коллекция Product, а вы вызываете метод у Shipment, который не статический.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как принятый, что бы закрыть